# Function is not defined error

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to create a 'rotating' DIV that changes automatically.
I have a function switchRotator(id) that changes the DIV's content using JQuery.
Here is the function that's causing the error:

```
function launchTimedRotator(){

//timedSwitch is a boolean value that can be enabled/disabled with buttons

if (timedSwitch) {

    if (counter<2) {
        counter++;
    } else {
        counter = 1;
    }

switchRotator(counter);
setInterval("launchTimedRotator()",3000);
return null;
}

};
```

As you can see I'm trying to use recursion by calling the function from itself in the end.
The error i receive in Google Chrome's Developer Tools is:
Uncaught ReferenceError: launchTimedRotator is not defined

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your function isn't global, which is required if you're passing a string. You could do `setInterval(launchTimedRotator,3000);`, but why recursion? You're going to have an exponential increase in the number of intervals that are running simultaneously.

Comment: I used recursion after seeing a similar concept on one of the "rotators". Will I have an increase? It simply calls itself and then ends, the function doesn't duplicate. Or am I missing something?

Comment: A `setInterval()` continuously runs the function every 3 seconds. So when it calls the function again, it's going to start another `setInterval`, but the original is still running, so now you have two. Then in another 3 seconds, the two will call the function again, creating two more, with the original two still running, making four, then eight, then sixteen... and so on.

Comment: `setInterval` will already call the function every 3 seconds. However you could use `setTimeout`.

Comment: *derp* Thanks, setTimeout is what I meant to use. Thanks for the explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using strings in the `setInterval()` is not very good practice. Use anonymous function instead:

```
setInterval(function() {
    launchTimedRotator();
}, 3000);
```

Though `setInterval` does not seem to be in its place. It will create many exemplars of intervals eventually. Maybe you intended to use `setTimeout` instead?

Generally, you can achieve the same effect both with `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`;

In case of `setInterval` it will be just `setInterval(function() {}, 3000)`, and in case of `setTimeout` it will be

```
function runTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        runTimeout();
    }, 3000);  
}
```

Personally I prefer `setTimeout()` as more reliable and manageable.

Comment: Or `setInterval(launchTimedRotator, 3000)`

Comment: SetTimeout is what i wanted, you're right. I used an anonymous function + setTimeout and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. I'm still new to JS syntax